# Building Table based on child values

Tags: xslt, parent, regex-lookarounds

Hi I'm trying to return a table based on a sample of the following input:

```
<Table TableLevel="1" TableNumber="1" TableTitle="">
  <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="1" class="Even">
    <TableHeader width="33" class="tableheadercell">
      <Paragraph>Account Name</Paragraph>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableHeader width="10" class="tableheadercell">
      <Paragraph>Type</Paragraph>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableHeader width="57" class="tableheadercell">
      <Paragraph>Additional Information</Paragraph>
    </TableHeader>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="2" class="OddLegacy">
    <TableCell>
      <Paragraph>ANONYMOUS LOGON</Paragraph>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <Paragraph>Group</Paragraph>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
        <ListItem>comment: ANONYMOUS LOGON</ListItem>
        <ListItem>group-id: 7</ListItem>
      </UnorderedList>
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="3" class="Even">
    <TableCell>
      <Paragraph>Administrators</Paragraph>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <Paragraph>Group</Paragraph>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
        <ListItem>group-id: 544</ListItem>
      </UnorderedList>
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Then my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="whiteuserxml">
    <item>ANONYMOUS LOGON</item>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="Table">
    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="TableRow[not(TableCell/Paragraph = $whiteuserxml/item)]">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(TableCell) = 0"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="TableHeader">
                <td><b><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></b></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="TableCell">
                        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
               </tr>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Administrators</td><td>Group</td><td>the other stufflist</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't prevent the table from being created if its going to be empty and by the time I work out whether it contains legitimate rows its too late to add the table name back

Comment: When posting XML, please ensure it is well-formed and formatted consistently.  I added the missing end-tag and reformatted the XML.

Comment: Your question(s) are ambiguous.  What does an "empty" input table look like? Does it still have a header row?  What do you mean by "add the table name back"?

Comment: In order for someone to help, they would need to have the requirements that the transformation must implement and a complete (but as small as possible) transformation that can be run to reproduce the problem. Currently you have provided none of these. I tried to run your XSLT fragment, but it uses undefined variables. Please, edit the question and provide the missing important information.

Comment: Apologies Jim first time asker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can move that choose up at table level and check if it contains cells

```
<xsl:when test="count(TableRow/TableCell) = 0"/>
```

Review:
Ok, with the "white list " conditions, still moving the condition up

```
<xsl:for-each select="Table[count(TableRow[not(TableCell/Paragraph = $whiteuserxml/item)]/TableCell)=0]">...
</xsl:when>
```

you will have to filter again in the inner loop.

The point is, you can build complex conditions with xslt/xpath that look forward (or other directions) in the data tree. You are not limited to the current node and attributes

Comment: I can't do the count UNTIL I've ensured that the rows in the source are not in the whitelist

Comment: Yep now I think I've got it ultimately a line to demonstrate what I was trying to do:
    `count(Section/Section[not(Table/TableRow/TableCell/Paragraph = $whiteuserxml/item)])`

This counts how many sections there are that don't contain low level child nodes that are in a certain list of nodes